# Is there a way to download video while keeping their chapters metadata?

Tags: python, bash, command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I've used many video downloaders before: atube catcher, 4k downloader, jDownloader, and currently using youtube-dl.
I can't download videos, [this](https://youtu.be/LnO42jxJaC4) for example, while still keeping their online chapters intact, like part1 is "intro" lasting from 00:00 to 00:45 and so on.
So far I tried these parameters with youtube-dl

## Filesystem

--write-annotations
--write-description
--write-info-json

## Thumbnail images

--write-all-thumbnails

## Video format

-f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]/worst'
--merge-output-format mp4

## Post-processing

--add-metadata
--embed-subs
--embed-thumbnail

Also tried requesting the mkv video format (thought maybe it was built into it) didn't help tho. 
I know these options don't really say anything about sections but I'm trying to get as much metadata as I can

Comment: Welcome to SO and please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Ahmet Can you please be more specific? I did read it and to my knowledge I made sure to follow them.

Comment: https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp supports `--split-chapters`, works quite nicely, also with audio

Comment: I vote for this to be on topic, and down vote on stackoverflow's policy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information you want is called chapters in the youtube-dl info JSON.

There is [a recent open pull request](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/pull/26297) for youtube-dl that fixes [a problem with this information](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/26005). In the current release of youtube-dl, if you use the `---write-info-json` or `--dump-json` you will see that the chapters information is null (`"chapters": null`). You can use the code in the fork repository to be able to obtain the information you want.

Follow these steps:

1. Clone [this repository](https://github.com/gschizas/youtube-dl):

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/gschizas/youtube-dl.git
   ```
2. Change to the repository directory:

   ```bash
   cd youtube-dl/
   ```
3. Checkout the pull request branch:

   ```bash
   git checkout bugfix/youtube/chapters-fix-extractor
   ```
4. Run youtube-dl from the current location:

   ```bash
   python -m youtube_dl --write-info-json https://youtu.be/LnO42jxJaC4
   ```

You will see information like this in the info JSON:

```json
"chapters": [
    {
        "start_time": 0.0,
        "end_time": 46.0,
        "title": "Intro"
    },
    {
        "start_time": 46.0,
        "end_time": 72.0,
        "title": "QOTD"
    },
    ...
]
```

Hopefully the fix will be accepted into the youtube-dl repository and included in future releases, so there will be no need to clone any repository.

Comment: thanks a lot.
1 thing to add is: I used this "python path/to/youtube_dl/__main__.py --arguments" instead so I can use it from anywhere in my .bat scripts